# Famous JS setTimeout twist

Tags: javascript

So we all know the ever-appearing JS question of what will log in this case:

```js
for (var i=0;i<5;i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, i*1000);
}
```

However, I've noticed that in certain environments this would log a result of setTimeout (timer id) first, and only after that the usual result. Why is that so? Is it because these environments (chrome console, ff firebug console) always expect/infer a "return" of the whole statement?

Comment: No repro here in Firebug console (Firefox 49.0.1, Firebug 2.0.17).

Comment: it's because dev tools print the last return value. That's pretty much it, really

Comment: Sorry, what does it log?  You didn't put the output in quotes or otherwise delimit it, so it isn't clear.

Comment: @Amy it prints the timer id (the return result of `setTimeout`) first then every 5 seconds it prints `5`.

Comment: I don't see why it should print the return value of `setTimeout`, nor does it do so in this snippet (that would be a miracle).

Comment: @trincot it does it if you run the code in the browser dev tools. It's because browser consoles always print out the return values. Easy to check by running `setTimeout(function(){})` by itself - you should get an integer back.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, @vlaz. The OP didn't run that code in the browser, but in dev tools.

Comment: @trincot yes indeed. It's not worded very well, but OP does mention dev tools towards the end. Essentially, the question boils down to "why do dev tools print the return value" and the answer is the rather boring "they just do" with the possible expansion of "it's to aid debugging". I'm not really sure this deserves a proper SO-style answer. Perhaps it's also been answered, actually, so I can check that.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome console shows returned value first (id of `setTimeout`). 
And after it `console.log`.